# Categorize spreadsheet lines - ala SQL GROUP

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

I want to consolidate a series of name-value pairs by name and sum the values. The pairs are in two columns of a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet, about a hundred rows.

Input:

[image]

Output, to another part of the spreadsheet:

[image]

If these were rows in an SQL table, I'd SELECT .. GROUP BY the first column.

I'd prefer it to be a relatively automated process, so I can add pairs later and update the categorized output without too much tedium.

I found some discussion of [Sorting and Grouping](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Sorting_and_Grouping) in something called ReportBuilder, but the output there seems to be to a Writer document. I want to stay in the spreadsheet because there will be further processing on the sums.

Comment: If the first column possibilities are relatively static, you could manually enter the a,b,c column and then use `=SUMIF(A$1:A$2000,H1,B$1:B$2000)` (assuming the original table is in columns A,B and the output table is in columns H,I) and copy-paste the formula down however many rows you have.  If the labels in the first column will change enough to make manual updating too much hassle, I'd look into Pivot Tables (sometimes called Data Pilots in Open/LibreOffice).

Answer (score 0):

use the [Pivot Feature](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Creating_Pivot_Tables) in Libre Office. 
Put the category as row field and the values as data field.

[Here](http://www.ahuka.com/?page_id=911) some Background Infos. Or Google with Libre Office Pivot table.